# What is the proper way of defining a DEBUG symbol for LLVM with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macros, compilation, llvm

I am using Xcode 3.2.5 with the LLVM 1.6 compiler. Some of my classes have conditional compilation code. I need to define the DEBUG macro at compile time rather than statically in a file.

I achieved this using OTHER_CFLAGS parameter available to define the DEBUG macro. However, I wonder if there is a better/cleaner way of doing it in Xcode ?

Environment:

OS: Mac OS X 10.6.6
Xcode 3.2.5
Compiler: LLVM 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entry "Preprocessor Macros" in your build settings

Comment: Great ! I feel my build is cleaner/better organized now. Thanks.